# How to deploy Nestjs and react combination to the Heroku

Tags: reactjs, web, heroku, deployment, nestjs

I'm trying to deploy my web application (nest + react) to the Heroku, but I cant't find a clear guide or explanation how to deploy this combination. There are a lot of guides how to deploy using nodejs + react, but this doesn't work with nestjs.
Can you provide me a guide or explain step by step what exactly I need to do?

Comment: Are you trying to have the Nest application serve the react application, or do you want to have the front end and back end on separate servers?

Comment: nestjs have to serve react application